# How to make popover view dismiss itself and set background image for nested UITableView

Tags: ipad, background, uipopovercontroller, dismiss

I have 2 question about popover view that:

I use popoverController to show a UIViewController with a NavigationController, in this viewController contain 2 UITableViews, Cancel and Done buttons on navigationController.

1 - When I tried to set background color or background image (by  [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ViewBg.png"]];), but there is no effect for both tableView and viewController.view. The background color still as default color.

2 - I would like to dismiss the popView when tapping on Cancel or Done button, I tried to pass popoverController to nested viewController then call dismissPopoverAnimated: but not luck.

Does anyone know how to do this please help me!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

1)
I guess you are setting colorWithPatternImage as BG on the UIViewController and not the tableViews.
 can you try `[table setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];` on both UITablesViews

2)
i guess you must have done something similar to:

```
in loadView:
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                            initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                   target:self 
                                                   action:@selector(dismissPopoverMethod)];


- (void)dismissPopOverMethod
{
     [referencedPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES]
}
```

Comment: That are exactly what I did, but no effect :(

Comment: for 1)did you do [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ViewBg.png"]]];  can you not add the tableViews and check if the bg is set? then add the tableViews with clearColor

Comment: Dear Gopal, What ever i did: leave view empty, set table background to clearColor, I sill cannot set my background color or image, no effect.